# Not able to install restify module in node.js in windows7?

Tags: node.js, restify

Actually i am going to run one application with command

> node C:....\path to my directory

But it is showing me

> Error: Cannot find module 'restify'

Can anybody solves this problem?

Comment: you need to install restify module `npm install restify`

Comment: i have used same command but then also its giving me same error

Comment: you should do npm install from the directory which contains node application

Comment: Switch to the directory that contains your app. `npm install restify`. What's the output? Now, run your app again. Output?